# How do you pick spells for NPCs?

Tags: invisible-sun

If I have an NPC who uses magic, how do I pick their spells?

I bring this up because I want to have the Apostates feel their counter/spellbreaker abilities are useful.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This site focuses on specific problems, and we can’t just give you thoughts and opinions. Can you rephrase your question to ask for what exactly you’re having a problem with, instead of asking for people’s thoughts? (You can [edit] at any time.)